# Replacement for Thyme

Tags: sauce

Im making a strawberry tart where the sauce is made from boiling thyme, port/tawny and strawberry juice. Is there any replacement for thyme in this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please give us a little more information? E.g., the reason you want to replace the thyme? Allergy? Dislike thyme? Looking for different flavor? This would help us give you better answers.

Comment: I am kind of surprised you are supposed to boil strawberry juice. When I have cooked strawberries the flavor disappeared completely.

Comment: @Willk, what about strawberry jam? That's not tasteless. Most juice-based sauces need some boiling to activate whatever is used to thicken them.

Answer (score 5):

The flavour of thyme can't be imitated by substitution. You can either omit it or devise a different sauce. Various herbs (basil for example) are combined with strawberries in various dishes, but the proportions are up to you. You may want to search for recipes using both strawberries and each of the available herbs to help with both selection and quantity.